# SQL select from each table from result set of tables

Tags: sql, select

I have a database named **db** with tables with the same schema such as:

**table_1, table_2, ...table_n**

Suppose each table has the columns '**key**' and '**value**' and I would like to select all the rows in all the n tables where **key = 'x'**

for example, for the following tables for key = '1':

table_1 = {'1' => 'aaa', '2' => 'xyz'}

table_2 = {'1' => 'bbb, '3' => 'zzz'}

table_3 = {'1' => 'ccc, '3' => 'xxx'}

I would expect the result set to be {'1' => 'aaa', '1' => 'bbb', '1' => 'ccc'}

I looked it up and found out that I can get all the tables by selecting them from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('value')
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA='db';
```

But now I need to find a way to iterate through the result set in such a manner (pseudo code):

```
foreach (table in tablesResultSet)
{ results += SELECT * FROM table WHERE key = 'x' }
```

I apologize for the crude pseudo code but I find that it is the best way to describe the issue.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: EAV over multiple tables. Great antipattern combo :/

Comment: Sounds to me like your schema leaves a lot to be desired. Dynamically determining which tables you want to select from generally means bad database design. Why aren't all of these records in one table. With a new column to delineate which `_N`(former table) they are a part of. Then you just have to `SELECT key, value FROM my_one_table WHERE key=1;`.

Comment: In the end though, you are going to have to construct one ugly-ass UNION query: `SELECT key, value FROM table_1 WHERE key=1 UNION ALL SELECT key, value FROM table_2 WHERE key_1 UNION ALL SELECT key, value FROM table_N WHERE key_1....`

Comment: @JNevill At a physical level in the DB it can make sense to have multiple tables (much easier for the phone company to work with 24 100GB tables than one 2.4TB table). But you want a setup where the DB does all this behind the scenes. The logical schema should be just the one table.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Yes. I agree. A single table that is partitioned, or even just properly indexed, would be the right solution here. I'm assuming OP doesn't have the ability to redesign the schema, but if this is an application in it's infancy, then it would be prudent to redesign and deal with the small fallout.

Comment: @JNevill In high-volume applications, an index isn't enough. But I think it's unlikely OP is ingesting terabytes per hour.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, multiple tables with the same schema go to one large logical table that is partitioned by date, location, or some other discriminator. This can be much more efficient in terms of archiving, querying, etc.

But if you want to do this, you should work with an RDBMS that supports table inheritance or some equivalent concept. You don't want to play with the internal structures of the DB, and then have to build a query on the fly dependent on the results.

Postgresql 10 allows you to set up a [partitioning scheme](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html) where almost everything is done for you; earlier versions (and 10 retains) inheritance relationships that let you do this with a little work. I suspect other vendors have similar capabilities, and if you really need a partitioned set-up (which can't be determined from your dummy example), I would choose an RDBMS on the basis of this capability.